# discord.py-rewrite - Best way to overwrite command cooldown

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I am writing commands with a cooldown on every single one. Like this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(...)
async def bot_command(ctx):
   pass
```

The problem with that is that the cooldown applies to every user. However, I want the cooldown to not apply to the bot developers (IDS are stored in a list). How can I do that in the more efficient way?

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the exception in an exception handler, and invoke the command manually from there.

```
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(...)
async def bot_command(ctx):
   pass

@bot_command.error
async def bot_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandOnCooldown):
        if ctx.author.id in list_of_ids:
            args = ()
            kwargs = {}
            await ctx.invoke(ctx.command, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise error
```

Note that [`Context.invoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoke) doesn't do anything but call the callback with the arguments provided.  You'll have to handle all the input conversion, pre/post invoke hooks, etc on your own.

Comment: @TheOneMusic Yes, but keep in mind that you'll have to prepare the arguments yourself.  (You may also be able to use [`Context.reinvoke`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.reinvoke), I'm not sure)